# using 'case' instead of 'If else' for Actions in action manager

Tags: delphi, if-statement, delphi-7, case

im working on **delph 7** application that has lots of **actions** (more than 50) using the action manager.
and to track each action i have ..as of now i have **if else** like the following code..

```
 procedure TMainForm.OnActionExecute(Sender: TObject);
    var
          Action : TBasicAction;
    begin
            Action := Sender as TBasicAction;
            if (Action is TAction) and not TAction(Action).Enabled then    exit;
           if Action = SQLQueryAction then
           begin
          //do somthing
           end
        else if (Action = NewSurveyAction) then
          begin
          //do somthing
          end
        else if ... 
         ..
         ..
        //lots of actions with if else latr..


    end;// of OnActionExecute....
```

can any one tell me

1. how to use the **'case'** like

   ```
      case actions of 
            SQLQueryAction    : //do somthing;
            newsurveyaction   : //do somthing;

           //lots more actions to go..

       end; //of case.
   ```

Comment: There may be other reasons for your setup, but you can also assign the OnExecute for each individual action and skip the case statement all together.  If several actions need the same execute they can share the same event handler.  I have worked on a project that uses Mason's approach with tags and it was difficult to track how everything was hooked up.  We now have each action using individual OnExecute handlers and it is much nicer to simply click once and jump right to the real execute code.

Comment: @MarkElder...yes that i tried, and like you said "it is much nicer"..i agree it is much nicer to jump to the real execute code..but since i had lots of actions (50+) , i wanted to have a them placed at a single location (in terms of single procedure) to track them down.

Comment: I can understand that motivation. What happened to us was every time we needed to verify or create an action we needed the following. 1) Open the action and look at the Tag property to see what number was assigned. 2) Go to the constants file and search for that number to find the constant name 3) Search for that constant name in the main case statement 4) Jump to the function called in the case statement. In the end we didn't save anything with a master function - especially since everything ended up in its own function anyway. It just ended up being more error prone. (I have ~150 actions)

Comment: ok yes..that can tedious and time consuming..i think for simplicity and fast (in terms of searching and all) and nice approach..the method you told is good and better option

Comment: @Mark you should make this an answer. While it doesn't directly answer the question as it was presented it's usually a better solution to the problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @PresleyDias; You can't just name each action and search for its execute method? You can't just double click on an action and see its code?  What you're doing is the opposite of helping yourself.  You have just destroyed the utility and convenience of actions by adding something you think will help you, that I can almost 100% guarantee only makes everything worse.

Comment: @MarkElder like Warren P suggest please answer it, it is better option then what im trying to do..!! like warren P said "What you're doing is the opposite of helping yourself"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use **case** on a non-ordinal type.  However, each action has a Tag property that holds an integer.  If you assign each action a Tag that maps to a constant, you can do something like this:

```
case action.tag of
  SQL_QUERY_TAG:  //do something
  NEW_SURVEY_TAG: //do something
  //etc
end;
```